# adding magnific popup for youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, magnific-popup

the window popup but video isn't playing.
it says ''The web page at file://www.youtube.com/embed/Nlw5FnHGER4?autoplay=1 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class= "popup" href= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlw5FnHGER4">play</a>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.popup').magnificPopup({
          type:"iframe",
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i am trying this with a image then it is working fine.

Comment: `file://www.youtube.com/embed/Nlw5FnHGER4?autoplay=1` - is this correct? - note the **file://**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo').magnificPopup({
      // disableOn: 700,
      type: 'iframe',
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      removalDelay: 160,
      preloader: false,
      iframe:{
        patterns:{
          youtube:{
          index: 'youtube.com',
          id: 'v=',
          src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%'
        },
      },
      srcAction:'iframe_src',
    },
      fixedContentPos: false
    });
  });
```

Declared src for iframe and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the video in a popup/another window try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
   <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>popup</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class= "popup" href= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nlw5FnHGER4">play</a>
  </body>
 </html>
```

please note the movement of all script tags to under the head, the updated URL, and the removal of

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.popup').magnificPopup({
          type:"iframe",
        })
      })
   </script>
```

if you want it embedded within the page (as an iframe) try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>popup</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.popup').magnificPopup({
              type:"iframe",
            })
          })
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe width="420" height="315" class= "popup" scr= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nlw5FnHGER4?autoplay=1">play</iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

also reference this site, w3 schools, [(here)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

also try it out here (option 1), RIGHT CLICK on the link in STACK OVERFLOWS ENGINE in any other you can just click on it but stack overflow requires you to right click and say "open in new tab"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class= "popup" href= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nlw5FnHGER4">play</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you RIGHT CLICK and select OPEN IN NEW TAB in stack overflow? (or use it in js.fiddle to just click)